# DoCmd.OpenForm -- where arg's still causing "ENTER PARAMETER" box

Tags: vba

When closing form B, I want it to open up form A to the record that was last on form B. I cannot figure out why I am still getting an "Enter Parameter" issue on this.

There is a button to close the form, and here is the sub function for the button...

```
Private Sub Close_Form_Click()
DoCmd.OpenForm "FormA", acNormal, , "[ID] = " & Me.ID
DoCmd.Close acForm, "FormB"
End Sub
```

Comment: This is more of a VB/programming question AFAICS - voting to close unless the database aspect is clarified.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. I was missing some quote marks. Since the IDs are alphanumeric instead of numeric, the code now looks like this (and works)

```
Private Sub Close_Form_Click()
DoCmd.OpenForm "FormA", acNormal, , "[ID] = '" & Me.ID & "'"
DoCmd.Close acForm, "FormB"
End Sub
```